# How to calculate NDSI of a specific region from an image collection?

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine

I want to calculate NDSI using Landsat8 data for 2015 - 2020 specific months to prepare binary snow cover maps (NDSI > 0.4) and then export all images based on my boundary area.
I tried out the below codes but NDSI does not work using attempts 1, 2 and 3:
The error for attempt 2 is: green.subtract is not a function
The error for attempt 2 is: image.normalizedDifference is not a function
The error for attempt 3 is: image.normalizedDifference is not a function

```
var roi: Table users/abdul/_Watershed-Boundary

var l8 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_TOA")

var image = l8.filterBounds(roi)

           .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER','less_than', 3)

           .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2015,2020,'year'))

           .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(11,4,'month'));
```

// Compute the Normalized Difference Vegetation Index (NDSI)

// **Attempt 1**:

```
 var green = image.select('B3');

 swir = image.select('B6');

 ndsi = green.subtract(swir).divide(green.add(swir)).rename('NDSI');
```

// **Attempt 2**:

```
 var greenBand = 'B3';

 var swirBand = 'B6';

 var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference([greenBand, swirBand]);
```

// **Attempt 3**:

```
var ndsi = image.normalizedDifference([B3,B6])

Map.addLayer(ndsi, {min:-1, max:1, palette:[]})
```

Answer (score 1):

Attempts 2 or 3 can be modified as follows. You cannot applied methods for images ('normalizedDifference') directly to an Image Collection. For this reason I produced the mean (img) for that collection (it could be used a function for each image in Image Collection).

```
var roi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-113.7614013671875, 40.54917381877071],
          [-113.7614013671875, 40.461463065241],
          [-113.6295654296875, 40.461463065241],
          [-113.6295654296875, 40.54917381877071]]], null, false);

var l8 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_TOA");

var image = l8.filterBounds(roi)
           .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER','less_than', 3)
           .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2015,2020,'year'))
           .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(11,4,'month'));

var img = image.mean().select(['B3', 'B6']);

var ndsi = img.normalizedDifference(['B6', 'B3'])
  .rename('NDSI')
  .clip(roi);

print(ndsi);

var imageVisParam = {"opacity":1,
                     "bands":["NDSI"],
                     "min":-0.1789,
                     "max":0.3323,
                     "palette":["fcff25","ffb354","1714ff"]};

Map.addLayer(ndsi, imageVisParam, 'NDSI');
Map.centerObject(roi);
```

Running above code in GEE code editor produces following result.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. 
My next question is how to map pixels as snow if NDSI  ≥ 0.4 and the rest as non-snow to create Landsat binary maps and then use it to calculate the snow cover fraction inside of a circle with a 500m radius centered at each MODIS pixel and finally export all my images.